# Optimal Setup for Joomla 2.5/3.in Azure

Tags: php, mysql, apache, azure, joomla

I'm researching hosting solutions and comparing optimal environments for installing Joomla 2.5. If we use a VM on Azure, what is the recommended version of Apache, MySQL and PHP? What flavor of Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

centos, nginx, mysql 5.6 newest PHP